# How to use Google Spreadsheet as a data source for Grafana?

Tags: google-sheets, grafana

I have a spreadsheet with our internal Team Healthcheck Meetings statistics.

It looks like that:

[image: spreadsheet example screenshot]

I wanna make Grafana dashboards to visualise how each Team Area's "Final Vote" (Teamwork — Yellow, Mission — Green) evolves from Sprint to Sprint (11, 12, 13 etc.).

I'm kind of newbie in software development... so, I tried to look for some kind of "plug-and-play" integrations, but it looks like neither Grafana nor G.Sheet doesn't have native integration modules.

Could someone recommend either tools / services or some strategy / steps to develop my own integration?

Answer (score 2):

Now there is an official Google Sheet plugin: https://github.com/grafana/google-sheets-datasource

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get a direct download link for a Google Sheets by using **Publish to the Web** feature

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965

You might want to select a TSV or CSV format, based on Grafana plugin that will work for you, here is a few Grafana datasources i've found:

- https://github.com/addshore/grafana-tsv-datasource
- https://github.com/SmartBlug/grafana-csv-datasource
- https://github.com/michaeldmoore/CSVServer